# RStudio freezes on "saving workspace image," previously saved .RData file disappears

Tags: r, rstudio, rdata

First, I've also posted this question on the RStudio Support page. If I get a response there, I will post it here for all to see (and vice versa).

I'm enjoying RStudio but am having trouble using Rprojects to save model outputs. I'm running sets of models that take ~1 day to run, so this is really setting me back. This is on an iMac running 10.9.5 (Mavericks).

Here's what happens:

I close the project and allow the "saving workspace image" to go through. (This is taking ~15 min, and the Rdata files are 6GB - this seems surprisingly large to me).

Often there is no problem upon reopening, the Rdata files are restored, and I see the objects I've created in the Global Environment pane. I run another model (or set of them), and close the project again. RStudio now gets hung up on "saving workspace image." Eventually, the wheel showing that this is active stops turning. Sometimes the mouse disappears from the screen and the entire computer freezes.

I either force RStudio to close, or force the computer to shutdown. When I restart and open RStudio, then load the Rproject, the Global Environment is empty. In the Files pane, there are no .RData files shown.

When I check the Rproject directory in Finder, there are multiple .RDataTmp (hidden) files. I'm not clear whether I can use any of them to recover my data, or how to attempt to load them in RStudio.

Solutions I've tried so far:

1. Updating everything, including R, RStudio, and Safari, per another post on RStudio Support.
2. Disabling my syncing program (SugarSync) from updating .Rproj.user file, also after reading a post there.
3. Enabling access for RStudio in the Privacy/Security settings.

I haven't been able to find any other possible solutions, and I am growing frustrated with testing this out, as it seems to happen only intermittently and (sigh) after the problem seems revolved, such that I've run a whole bunch of models and have a good deal of data to lose! This makes me wonder whether (a) the universe is simply cruel, or (b) it's the large file size that is causing the problem. The other option is (c) both.

I read elsewhere on RStudio Support that file compression can be enabled, but that this will slow the process of saving. Since it's already taking quite a long time to save upon closing the project and I'm not clear on why it might help, I'm hesitant to enable file compression until I know more.

Thanks for your help,

MK

Comment: When saving the workspace, RStudio just calls R's `save.image()` command. Are you able to reproduce this when running R from the terminal vs. RStudio itself? Either way, it's highly likely that your system is just running out of RAM and barfing. You might consider fitting and saving models in batches, to avoid exhausting available memory.

Comment: Seems like this is a RAM problem as you suggest. I'm using the save( ) command now to save the models as I go, then load( ) when I restart the program and make model comparisons. It's still crashing once in a while, but since I'm not losing the outputs each time, it's tolerable--and an ok tradeoff for the time saved in looking at model plot outputs via RStudio rather than the R terminal. (If you add this as an answer rather than a comment, I'll approve the solution).